# want to put limit in list at time of retrieving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
    public class FriendModel {

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("userid")
    @Expose
    private String userid;
    @SerializedName("photourl")
    @Expose
    private String photourl;
    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private List<Message> messages = null;
}
```

I am using firebaserecycler adapter that populates FriendModel in a list.

In each object of the FriendModel list, I have another list which is  List of Message.
What I want is to get the last item of this Message list.I have to show the last item in my same adapter. Is there any way to add this limitation to my List.  My List of Message can be very long can contains tons of items so I don't want to hold all objects in my Message list that's why I need to do this.
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: firebase has a limitToLast() function, you can ask it only to show the last 5 or 10 or 50 (whatever number you pick)

Comment: @chornge : I want to limit the Message list. limit toLast work in FriendModel list

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would suggest you define a separate class for "messages". So hold all user data in 'FriendModel' class and store all messages in a class called 'Messages'. In your firebase database store the messages against a specific FriendModel.userid. 
That way you can retrieve the list of messages separately from the FriendModel. And when retrieving the list of messages use the 'limitToLast' constraint to retrieve only 1 message like in the example below

```
Query recentMessageQuery = databaseReference.child(userid).child("messages").limitToLast(1);
```

Please let me know if you need a more detailed explanation. But this should get you started -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: I know it already but I dont want to do it as I have to call it as many times as the size of my FriendModel List

Comment: @TUSHAR - Not necessarily. You can call the messages node ones and you will get an array of datasnapshot that you can iterate through. Alternatively, you can just store the last message of your "messages" as a variable in the FriendModel. But as a matter of good design you should only  keep in FriendModel what you want to show in your recyclerview. It will make for an elegant UX.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this method that returns the last element of your `messages` list.

```
static Message getLastMessage(List<Message> list) {
    int listSize = list.size();
    return list.get(listSize-1);
}
```

Comment: My problem will not be solved by this as i dont want to hold all the items of message list.What I am asking is that is there any method like annotation that put limit in the size of message list in firebase recycler adapter

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will retrieve all those messages even you do some local tricks to store only the last N messages in the list. Therefore you need to change your structure and flatten your data. Only the message ids/keys should be stored in a list in your `FriendModel`. This way, you will be avoiding the overhead of retrieving all the messages, however, you have to make another call to get the last message itself.

For the solution I mention, you can update your database as follows:

[image: Proposed "friends" path]

[image: Proposed "messages" path]

Then you should update your `FriendModel` class like this:

```
public class FriendModel {

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("userid")
    @Expose
    private String userid;
    @SerializedName("photourl")
    @Expose
    private String photourl;
    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, Boolean> messages;

    // Getters and setters...

    @Exclude
    public String getLastMessageKey() {
        if (messages != null) {
            SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(messages.keySet());
            return keys.last();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to retrieve friend and the last message, you can do as follows:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("friends").child("1111111111");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        FriendModel friend = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendModel.class);
        String lastMessageKey = friend.getLastMessageKey();

        if (lastMessageKey != null) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").child(lastMessageKey)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    MessageModel lastMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageModel.class);
                    // Now you have the last message.
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I have another idea
I will remove say first hundred messages if the messagelist exceeds from some specific limit & save those removed messages in some other table & when I want to retrieve the messages then I can use limittoLast & add those in the messagelist again to show those removed messages....If We can put some limit say just by annotation then my problem will be solved immediately without much pain......

Answer (score 0):

There is no method or API in firebase that fetches the only custom number of items from a list inside a model class.

You have to get all the messages and store it locally in list variable. If you want to show only last message use the following code in `onBindViewHolder` method of the recyclerview adapter class -

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        FriendModel frdModelObj = frdModelList.get(position);
        List<Message> messagesList = frdModelObj.getMessages();
        String lastMessage = messagesList.get(messagesList.size()-1);
}
```